# Oracle Rac With Scan Error

Tags: oracle, rac, listener

I have installed Oracle RAC with ASM on Oracle Linux 5.8. My database version is 11.2.0.1.
I have 2 node in my plan and all of them are active.
I set scan  in my DNS server but I can not connect to database with scan listener. I can connect to each node with their VIP.
Some of data about listener is listed in below.

```
[grid@rac1 ~]$ srvctl config scan_listener
SCAN Listener LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1 exists. Port: TCP:1521

[grid@rac1 ~]$ srvctl status scan_listener
SCAN Listener LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1 is enabled
SCAN listener LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1 is running on node rac1

[grid@rac1 ~]$ lsnrctl status LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1


LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-JUL-2015 05:46:23


Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                02-JUL-2015 05:04:58
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 41 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/log/diag/tnslsnr/rac1/listnere_scan_1_scan1/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.245)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully


[grid@rac1 ~]$ lsnrctl sERVICES LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1


LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-JUL-2015 05:46:58


Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:blocked
         REMOTE SERVER
         (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac1-vip)(PORT=1521)))
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:blocked
         REMOTE SERVER
         (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac2-vip)(PORT=1521)))
Service "orclXDB" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: rac1.localdomain, pid: 5305>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=rac1.localdomain)(PORT=30855))
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: rac2.localdomain, pid: 5293>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=rac2.localdomain)(PORT=36946))
The command completed successfully



[grid@rac1 ~]$nano /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1))))          # $
LISTENER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER))))            # line added by Agent
# listener.ora.rac1 Network Configuration File: /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora.rac1
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.


ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER_SCAN1 = ON


ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER1 = ON


LISTENER_SCAN1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = LISTENER_SCAN1))
    )
  )


ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER=ON              # line added by Agent
ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTNERE_SCAN_1_SCAN1=ON         # line added by Agent

[oracle@rac1 ~]$ nano /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac-scan.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )



[oracle@rac1 ~]$ nano /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-JUL-2015 05:56:20

Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac-scan.localdomain)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
OK (20 msec)
```

The error when I want to connect to racdb with scan name is:

```
[oracle@rac1 ~]$ sqlplus system/oracle@orcl


SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 2 05:57:03 2015


Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


ERROR:
ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server
```

Comment: Services are in the `state:blocked`. Is the name resolution set up correctly for public and VIP names? (DNS or `/etc/hosts`)

Comment: In dns i set rac-scan and in /etc/hosts i set public and vip and private ip for  all of nodes . where can i check state of services ?

Comment: For the local listeners: `lsnrctl status listener`, `lsnrctl services listener`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and local listener was null, fixed it when enetered proper values

I'm no expert in RAC but here is how they could look

```
show parameter listener

NAME                       TYPE                 VALUE
-------------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
listener_networks          string               ((NAME=network2)(LOCAL_LISTENER=ot1pfcrs001_net002p)(REMOTE_LISTENER=ot1pfcrs001_net2))
local_listener             string               (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.101.73.140)(PORT=1541))
remote_listener            string               ot1pfcrs001.database.dv.hgn:1541
```